# In B2B applications where are the T&C and Privacy policy placed usually?

Tags: navigation, privacy, b2b

I'm designing the legal modules for a B2B application that is accessed via a browser. This application mainly shows different kinds of performance reports. When logging in for the 1st time, users need to agree to the T&C and privacy policy. But for subsequent visits, it needs to be there for future reference.

My question is - Where could the T&C and Privacy policy be located in such applications? For B2C websites it's usually in the footer.

Answer (score 1):

Usually legal agreements in software are expressed through a master service agreement and other contractual documents. They’re usually read and handled by the business’ legal or operations officers, not the end user.

Comment: Yes thats true, but not always. in this case there are terms the user that is using this needs to agree to as well.

Answer (score 1):

If the agreement to the T&C and Privacy policy is a must-have before the user can use the site, then showing a message up front as a modal overlay is perhaps the best way to ensure that the user sees them and agrees to them. This can be somewhat jarring but the impact can be somewhat reduced down by keeping the text  and imagery simple and easy to follow.
The links to the actual T&C and Privacy can also be on the footer precisely because most people expect them there.